# JQM crashes Blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

Prior to deploying JQuery Mobile js script to Blackberry application, simulator(Blackberry Bold 9700) crashes throwing an error "Class 'net.rim.device.api.crypto.MD5Digest' not found". I also renamed all dashes to dots, so this may not be the case of error, without a script application starts and works fine, but without JQM obviously, I also tried cleaning simulator. Does anyone comes with a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery Mobile pre 1.1 then make sure you are using jQuery Core 1.6.4.

I got `white-screens` when I used jQuery Core 1.7 with jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final, no problems on iOS or Android devices, just with BlackBerry.

If you are using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC-1 then you should be able to use jQuery Core 1.7.1 but I have not tested this.

Comment: I've spent many hours on this. Got my simple Cordova app working with Underscore and Backbone, but Jquery would make the whole app crash. Using 1.6.4 as said fixed the situation. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

doing a quick search I found this BlackBerry Support Forum thread:

[Application Entry Point Runtime Exceptions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Application-Entry-Point-Runtime-Exception/m-p/745721#M141038)

the solution post is:

> Lesson learned: if it doesn't work and you have no idea why, wipe/clean the device/simulator and/or make a new project and re-add all your source/resource files.

Comment: The link was inside a code block, which doesn't render as an anchor tag.